# Apache spark installation and db_metastore

Tags: apache-spark

I am beginner in Spark.
I installed java and spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6.tgz(I have not installed Hadoop) and with out changing any configuration in conf directory ran spark-shell.
In the director where spark is installed , I see another metastore_db created with tmp folder inside it.
why is this metastore_db is created , where is this configured ?
Also I see sqlContext being created after running spark-shell, what does this sqlContext represent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When running spark-shell, a SparkContext and SQLContext are created. SQLContext is an extension of SparkContext to enable support of [Spark SQL](http://spark.apache.org/sql/). It has method to execute sql queries (method sql) and to create DataFrames.

db_metastore is a Hive metastore path. Spark support Apache Hive queries via HiveContext. If there is no hive-site.xml configured, Spark will use db_metastore path, see [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/sql-programming-guide.html#tab_scala_14) for details.

However, it would be good if you will download Spark 2.0. There you've got unified entry point to Spark, named SparkSession. This class allows you to read data from many sources, create Datasets, etc.

Comment: Thank you for explaining

Comment: If it's helpful please mark question as answered - other people will not open question to give answer :)